# Rails 5 - Multiple Foreign keys belongs to the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Order model that belongs to a LoadingStation model. And the the LoadingStation will be used two times in the Order table, so it looks like:

```
class CreateLoadingStations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :loading_stations do |t|
      t.integer :type
      t.string :comp_name1
      t.string :street
      t.string :street_num
      t.string :zip_code
      t.string :city

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  end



 class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
         create_table :orders do |t|
          t.string :status
          t.belongs_to :loading_station, class_name: "LoadingStation", index: true, foreign_key: "loading_station_id"
          t.belongs_to :unloading_station, class_name: "LoadingStation", index: true, foreign_key: "unloading_station_id"

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

When I let run **rails db:migrate** I got this error:
**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "unloading_stations" does not exist**

Mmmmmm, seems to be that the class_name was not correct detected. The class_name should be the same in both statements, correct ?

Let check the model of Loading Station:

```
 class LoadingStation < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Okay, I change the CreateOrders migration:

```
 t.belongs_to :loading_station, class_name: "LoadingStation", index: true, foreign_key: "unloading_station_id"
```

Now when I let run the rails db:migrate I got this error:
**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateObject: ERROR:  constraint "fk_rails_5294e269cc" for relation "orders" already exists**

Okay, I understand the Foreign Key in the database seems to be identical and the database declines the migration task.

But what is the sense of the foreign_key: option when I define who different foreign_key names, when the database detects two identical ?

**Appendix:**

Here my Order model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**Final Question**

And at the end - among the error messages - I want to have two Foreign Keys pointing to the same table.

Comment: how does your `Order` model look? Do you actually have `unloading_station` association defined?

Answer (score 6):

I'll just focus on the code that allows you to reference the loading station table twice

In Rails 5.1 or greater you can do it like this:

### Migration

```
class createOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table(:orders) do |t|
        t.references :loading_station, foreign_key: true
        t.references :unloading_station, foreign_key: { to_table: 'loading_stations' }
    end
  end
end
```

This will create the fields `loading_station_id`, and `unloading_station_id` and make the database level references to the `loading_stations` table

### Models

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loading_station
  belongs_to :unloading_station, class_name: "LoadingStation"
end

class LoadingStation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :load_orders, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "loading_station_id"
  has_many :unload_orders, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "unloading_station_id"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not created a unloading_station model.

Comment: Yes, I don't want create extra models. I want to have only two Foreign Keys point to the same table. I think the syntax after the **t.belongs_to** is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any error on creating migrations with followings:

```
t.belongs_to :loading_station, class_name: "LoadingStation", index: true, foreign_key: "loading_station_id"

t.belongs_to :unloading_station, class_name: "LoadingStation", index: true, foreign_key: "unloading_station_id"
```

and the Order table looks like:

```
Order(id: integer, status: string, loading_station_id: integer, unloading_station_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

so it has necessary ids which you need!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up what should to be in the migration and what should to be in the model (and I don't mean this in a derogative way so please don't take it that way).

I have put together a rails 5 project for you to demonstrate what I think you want to achieve:

In summary I believe you're looking to have both the loading and unloading stations stored in the one table, but reference them separately as attributes of the order. In other words you're looking for single-table inheritance.

This is what I built quickly:

```
# app/models/order.rb
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :loading_station, optional: true
  belongs_to :unloading_station, optional: true
end

# app/models/station.rb
class Station < ApplicationRecord
end

# app/models/loading_station.rb
class LoadingStation < Station
  has_many :orders
end

# app/models/unloading_station.rb
class UnloadingStation < Station
  has_many :orders
end
```

As you can see the `LoadingStation` and `UnloadingStation` models inherit the `Station` model. The `Station` model gets a table in the database.

```
# db/migrate/20170826085833_create_orders.rb
class CreateStations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :stations do |t|
      t.string :comp_name1
      t.string :street
      t.string :street_num
      t.string :zip_code
      t.string :city
      t.string :type, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The type column is defined as a `:string` and holds the class name of the subclassed models, either `LoadingStation` or `UnloadingStation`.

And the orders table migration looks like this:

```
# db/migrate/20170826085833_create_orders.rb
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.belongs_to :loading_station, null: true, index: true
      t.belongs_to :unloading_station, null: true, index: true
      t.string :status
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see it references the `LoadingStation.id` and `UnloadingStation.id`. I wasn't sure whether or not these attributes were mandatory, so I set them to `null: false` in the column definitions and `optional: true` in the `Order` model.

To test that this works I created one LoadingStation, one UnloadingStation and one Order in the database seeds:

```
# db/seeds.rb
loading_station_1 = LoadingStation.create!(
  comp_name1: "Loading Station 1",
  street: "Park Ave",
  street_num: "300",
  zip_code: 10001,
  city: "NY"
)

unloading_station_4 = UnloadingStation.create!(
  comp_name1: "Unloading Station 4",
  street: "Madison Ave",
  street_num: "204",
  zip_code: 10001,
  city: "NY"
)

Order.create!(
  loading_station: loading_station_1,
  unloading_station: unloading_station_4,
  status: "delivered"
)
```

To test all this, simply create the database, run the migrations and execute the seeds:

```
rails db:create
rails db:migrate
rails db:seed
```

To test the result live open the `rails console`:

```
irb(main):001:0> pp Station.all

Station Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "stations".* FROM "stations"
[#<LoadingStation:0x007fcb8ac39440
  id: 1,
  comp_name1: "Loading Station 1",
  street: "Park Ave",
  street_num: "300",
  zip_code: "10001",
  city: "NY",
  type: "LoadingStation",
  created_at: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:06:53 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:06:53 UTC +00:00>,
 #<UnloadingStation:0x007fcb8ac39288
  id: 2,
  comp_name1: "Unloading Station 4",
  street: "Madison Ave",
  street_num: "204",
  zip_code: "10001",
  city: "NY",
  type: "UnloadingStation",
  created_at: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:06:53 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:06:53 UTC +00:00>]

irb(main):002:0> pp Order.all

Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders"
[#<Order:0x007fcb8bca2700
  id: 1,
  loading_station_id: 1,
  unloading_station_id: 2,
  status: "delivered">]

irb(main):003:0> order = Order.first

Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Order id: 1, loading_station_id: 1, unloading_station_id: 2, status:  "delivered">

irb(main):004:0> pp order.loading_station

LoadingStation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stations".* FROM "stations" WHERE "stations"."type" IN ('LoadingStation') AND "stations"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<LoadingStation:0x007fcb8c0e4390
 id: 1,
 comp_name1: "Loading Station 1",
 street: "Park Ave",
 street_num: "300",
 zip_code: "10001",
 city: "NY",
 type: "LoadingStation",
 created_at: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:06:53 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:06:53 UTC +00:00>

irb(main):005:0> pp order.unloading_station

UnloadingStation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "stations".* FROM "stations" WHERE "stations"."type" IN ('UnloadingStation') AND "stations"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<UnloadingStation:0x007fcb8a36a378
 id: 2,
 comp_name1: "Unloading Station 4",
 street: "Madison Ave",
 street_num: "204",
 zip_code: "10001",
 city: "NY",
 type: "UnloadingStation",
 created_at: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:06:53 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:06:53 UTC +00:00>

irb(main):006:0> pp order.status

"delivered"
```

I hope this helps you. I have checked the code into github, you can access it at https://github.com/JurgenJocubeit/SO-41796815.