# Ruby - migration reference represented in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Ok, so what I have is:

> Two entities: `games` and `apps`. They have a relation from `apps` to `games`:
>
> - On the migration it is as follows: `add_reference :apps, :games, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true`
> - On `app` model it is like this: `belongs_to :game`
> - On `game` model it is like this: `has_many :apps`

Right now that allows me to have an `app` and assign it a `game` (in the DB it shows a new column as `game_id` on `app` table).

What I want to do now is add a column with another game called `requested_game`.

To do that I added the following migration: `add_reference :apps, :requested_game, type: :uuid, foreign_key: { to_table: :games }`, but now I do not know how to show that relation in the models.

Any ideas? Do I have to create a `requested_game` model and reference it to the `game` model? I'm kinda lost right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57322588/4885323) about multiple foreign keys placed on a single table might get you what you need.

To extrapolate a bit, it sounds like you might ultimately want instances of your `App` model to have multiple methods attached to it? For example:

```
new_app = App.first
new_app.game
=> old_game
new_app.requested_game
=> newly_requested_game
```

If that's what you want then, as explained in the link above, you'll want the `apps` table to have two foreign keys on it, both pointing to the `games` table. Naturally, you'll have to give the table columns and corresponding `belongs_to` methods in the `game` table the proper options to know which is which.

I don't think you'll need to create a RequestedGame model unless you want to create instances of that model with its own methods and whatnot. So if you wanted to run something like requested_game.app, that model might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have an app that has:

1. A Game that is linked to the app by `game_id`
2. A Requested Game that is linked to the app by `requested_game_id`

In essence, it is 2 links from the table `apps` to the table `games` with 2 different foreign keys.

So in the model App, you can write like this:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'game_id'
  belongs_to :requested_game, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'requested_game_id'
end

# Or with newer versions of Rails

class App < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'game_id'
  belongs_to :requested_game, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'requested_game_id'
end
```

In the model Game, you can write like this:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apps, class_name: 'App', foreign_key: 'game_id'
  has_many :requesting_apps, class_name: 'App', foreign_key: 'requested_game_id'
end

# Or with newer versions of Rails

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :apps, class_name: 'App', foreign_key: 'game_id'
  has_many :requesting_apps, class_name: 'App', foreign_key: 'requested_game_id'
end
```

Comment: You don't need `foreign_key: 'requested_game_id'` on the `belongs_to` assocation as its deduced from the name of the assocation and not the class name. And the inverse relationship should be named something more like `requesting_apps` (as they are doing the requesting).

Comment: It is true that in the case if the `belongs_to` we don't need to specify the foreign_key, but I like explicit code in this case.

Thanks for suggesting the name `requesting_apps`. It is correct.